Scrapy Issue: HTML content discrepancy between Chrome and scraped output in Python
I’m working on a Scrapy project where I need to scrape data from the following Japanese website: text. The goal is to automate the extraction of data from each listing on this page.
The link for the listings follow this pattern: text whereby the number varies from listing to listing.
The HTML that Scrapy retrieves seems to be missing and/or different from the content visible in Chrome’s Inspect Element. To be more specific, I can't see the links of the listings within the html content.
My question is now, why might the HTML content scrapy retrieves differ from what’s visible in Chrome? Could this be due to JavaScript rendering or so? And how can I ensure that scrapy retrieves the same content as what I see in Chrome? In best case without loading additional packages, if possible.
Here my code:
import time
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
import re


class DetachedHouseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'detached_house'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.e-uchina.net']
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)'
                      'AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                      ' Version/17.4.1 Safari/605.1.15',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.e-uchina.net/house'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, 
                             callback=self.parse,
                             headers=self.headers
                             )

    def parse(self, response):
        # Extract the links to each lisiting detail page
        links = "//a[@class='show-for-small-only link-dummy']/@href"
        listings = response.xpath(links).getall()

        for listing in listings:
            # Construct absolute URL and
            # yield a request to parse the listing page
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(listing)
     
            yield scrapy.Request(absolute_url,
                                 callback=self.parse_listings,
                                 headers=self.headers
                                 )

    def parse_listings(self, response):
        price = response.xpath(".//*[@class='price']/text()").get()  # YEN
        yield {
               "price": int("".join(re.match(r"[0-9]+,[0-9]+",
                                             price)[0].split(","))) * 10000,
               }


def spider_result():
    results = []

    def crawler_results(item):
        results.append(item)

    dispatcher.connect(crawler_results, signal=signals.item_scraped)
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(DetachedHouseSpider)
    process.start()
    return results


data = spider_result()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())

Because it did not worked, I used this snippet to check the html content:
import request
from scrapy import Selector


url = "https://www.e-uchina.net/house"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.4.1 Safari/605.1.15'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
sel = Selector(text=page)
sel.getall()

I hope I did not forget anything when copying the code!
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It's certainly possible that JavaScript can be used to modify the page in the browser.  You can dig more into that by examining the response from the server in your browser, not the resulting rendered DOM.  If you need to emulate browser functionality in your scraping then you're probably looking for "headless browser" tools like Selenium.

First, detail links is loaded from this link https://www.e-uchina.net/api/search?searchType=house&mode=bukken&sort=video&perPage=20 by app.js in the top page. So you can not find those links in the response text and continue scraping.
Second, this code below can work fine.
import time
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.signalmanager import dispatcher
import re
import json


class DetachedHouseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'detached_house'
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.e-uchina.net']
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)'
                      'AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                      ' Version/17.4.1 Safari/605.1.15',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.e-uchina.net/api/search?searchType=house&mode=bukken&sort=video&perPage=20'
        yield scrapy.Request(url,
                             callback=self.parse,
                             headers=self.headers
                             )

    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            data = json.loads(response.text)
            for d in data.get('data', {}).get('bukkens', {}).get('data', []):
                price = d.get('bukken', {}).get('price_sort')  # YEN
                if price is not None:
                    yield {
                        "price": int(price.split('.')[0]) * 10000,
                    }
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.exception(e)


Hi Vassiliev,
Thank you very much for your help. This link and your code has been incredibly helpful! I just made a few adjustments, because I wanted to access the link of each listing and scrape a table from the individual pages. However, I noticed that the JSON data contains a lot of the information, so it might not be necessary to visit each link after all. I’ll check to see if the JSON data suffices.
data = json.loads(response.text)
    for d in data.get('data', {}).get('bukkens', {}).get('data', []):
        links = d.get('permalink')
        # rest of the code


Glad to help :)  @sheakz
